# Ubuntu 15.04 Gnome 3 mouse pointer incorrect size upon boot

Tags: gnome, 15.04, mouse, gtk, mouse-pointer

I have a Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition (project sputnik) running Ubuntu 15.04. It has a 3200x1800 display, so I have set window scale to 2 with `gnome-tweak`. When I boot into GNOME Shell 3.14.4 about three out of four times, my mouse is about half the size it should be.

I imagine this is due to Gnome incorrectly setting my mouse's scale to 1, instead of 2. Interestingly enough, the mouse will resize to the correct size if I run a GTK+ application, such as `nautilus` or `gnome-terminal`, and stays scaled correctly until another power cycle.

Does anyone have any experience with scaling issues with hi-dpi on Gnome? Does anyone know where the scale is set, and if it can be corrected upon boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem on my XPS 13 but using Unity desktop environment.

---

You can try the workaround that solved the problem for me. Edit your `x11-common` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/Xresources/x11-common
```

And add the following line to the end of the file :

```
export XCURSOR_SIZE=48
```

Comment: Seems to have worked over 4 reboots. Give me a day or two of power cycles and if I don't experience it again, I'll accept the answer. On a side note, since you have an XPS 13: Do you experience tty flickering on text bootup/shutdown sometimes? It's almost as my refresh rate is off.

Comment: 4 reboots ? uh that is strange... What do you call text bootup ? In my case I only experience flickering on Ubuntu splashscreen at shutdown (corrected in kernel 4.1.6)...

Comment: Yes, I power cycled 4 times, on the spot since my problem seemed somewhat random. Have power cycled more since and seems good. Text bootup as in boot to tty1, instead of booting into a desktop manager GUI.